# Set App Title dynamically according to domain name in Angular 2 Seed project

Tags: angular, angular-seed

I want to change the Angular 2 Seed app name using a running environment variable. I have two domain and two environments (DEV, PROD) for each of one and I want to change app name dynamically on running the application

I try to change the APP_NAME variable in ProjectConfig class which extends SeedConfig class. When I use environment TITLE variable in ProjectConfig, the program does not run.

I set `this.APP_TITLE = Config.TITLE;` in ProjectConfig class. (Config.TITLE comes from the environment.)

I want to show running current domain name on APP TITLE section.

In the `index.html` file there is a line

```
 <title><%= APP_TITLE %></title>
```

which take the App title from ProjectConfig APP_TITLE variable. I try to change APP_TITLE variable using my env TITLE variable so I could dynamically set the app name. I have two apps such as "APP NAME 1", "APP NAME 2". I have two environments (DEV, PROD) for each domain and four environment dev.ts, prod.ts, dev2.ts, prod2.ts which use EnvConfig interface. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhBPX.png)
when I run

```
npm start -- --env-config dev
```

APP NAME 1 run in dev mode.

```
npm start -- --env-config dev2
```

APP NAME 2 run in dev mode.

In brief, I want to show running app name dynamically on APP_TITLE section of index.html

Comment: Could you provide us with some code or a link to this "seed project"?

Comment: Ok, i give some detail. I update the question.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? i just want to set index.html *title* field with environment variable *TITLE* which coming dynamcally.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem with using Title service at [angular.io/guide/set-document-title](http://angular.io/guide/set-document-title)

I just add the code in app.component.ts file

```
 this.titleService.setTitle(Config.TITLE);
```

Config.TITLE value comes from environment variable dynamically.